# Dataform OK/SAVE button stays disabled when editing a nested object

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, dataform

I have been working with a DataForm from the toolkit and now I realize that I apparently have problems with the IEditableObject interface. The dataform in bound to an object that has 2 sub-object. All the field for the parent object and the 2 sub objects are on the same form. When I modify a datafield from the parent object the "OK" button become enabled but when I play with 2 out of 3 fields from the sub-object the "OK" button remains disabled. I have tried to investigate the differences between the fields and they seem to be all the same has someone face the same issue?

In the sample below the fields NumberWrapper and LabelWrapper belong to the parent object then Stc1Wrapper is an object that is part of the parent object the field label DOES trigger the ok button but the telephone number and transfer code field do not. The underlying implemention of the 3 fields of Stc1Wrapper all seem identical. I am stuck here I cannot find proper MSDN documentation on this dataform control since it comes from the toolkit which is unfortunate.

```
<toolkit:DataForm Grid.Column="1" 
                          Margin="0,94,0,0" 
                          Width="350"
                          Name="EsnDataForm" 
                          Header="Esn Item"
                          AutoGenerateFields="False" 
                          CurrentItem="{Binding ElementName=MyGrid, Path=SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                          AutoEdit="False" 
                          AutoCommit="False"
                          CommandButtonsVisibility="Cancel,Edit,Commit"
                          CommitButtonContent="Save"
                          CancelButtonContent="Cancel">
            <toolkit:DataForm.NewItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <toolkit:DataField Label="Number" IsReadOnly="True" >
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding NumberWrapper,Mode=TwoWay}" MaxLength="9" Width="120" IsReadOnly="True" />
                        </toolkit:DataField>
                        <toolkit:DataField Label="Label" Grid.Row="1" >
                            <TextBox Name="NameBox" Text="{Binding LabelWrapper,Mode=TwoWay}" MaxLength="32" Width="120" />
                        </toolkit:DataField>
                        <toolkit:DataField Label="Sub Label" Grid.Row="2" >
                            <TextBox Name="SubLabelBox" Text="{Binding PrimaryPsapLabelWrapper,Mode=TwoWay}" MaxLength="32" Width="120" />
                        </toolkit:DataField><toolkit:DataField Label="Label" Margin="-50,1,1,1" >
                            <TextBox Name="Stc1LabelBox" Text="{Binding Stc1Wrapper.LabelWrapper, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxLength="32" Width="120" />
                        </toolkit:DataField>
                        <toolkit:DataField Label="Telephone Number" Margin="-50,1,1,1" >
                            <TextBox Name="Stc1TelephoneBox" Text="{Binding Stc1Wrapper.TnWrapper, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxLength="10" Width="120" />
                        </toolkit:DataField>
                        <toolkit:DataField Label="Transfer Code" Margin="-50,1,1,1" >
                            <TextBox Name="Stc1TransferCodeBox" Text="{Binding Stc1Wrapper.TransferCodeWrapper, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="120" />
                        </toolkit:DataField>
                    [...]

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public string TransferCodeWrapper
    {
        get
        {
            return this.TransferCode;
        }
        set
        {
            ValidateRequired("TransferCodeWrapper", value, "Transfer Code is mandatory");
            ValidateRegularExpression("TransferCodeWrapper", value, @"^[\*]\d{1,3}$", "The format should be * followed by 1 to 3 digits");
            this.TransferCode = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("TransferCodeWrapper");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public string TnWrapper
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Tn;
        }
        set
        {
            ValidateRequired("TnWrapper", value, "Telephone number is mandatory when Type is Telephone Number");
            ValidateRegularExpression("TnWrapper", value, @"^\d{10}$", "The telephone number should be 10 digits");
            this.Tn = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("TnWrapper");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public string LabelWrapper
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Label;
        }
        set
        {
            ValidateRequired("LabelWrapper", value, "Label is required");
            ValidateRegularExpression("LabelWrapper", value, @"^[\w-_ ]$+", "Characters allowed (a-z,A-Z,0-9,-,_, )");
            this.Label = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("LabelWrapper");
        }
    }
```